# In Java, can a method/constructor declaration appear inside another method/constructor declaration?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, jls

In Java, can a method/constructor declaration appear inside another method/constructor declaration? Example:

```
void A() { 
    int B() { }
}
```

I think not, but I'd love to be reassured.

Comment: Not even for constructor inside constructor?

Comment: What would be the point? Constructors create instances of classes, not instances of other constructors :)

Comment: just a thought , what about method level inner class , which has anonyomous constructor.

Comment: @Suresh S: Yeah, I am aware of that possibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. it is not compilable.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. 
For reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but you *can* have a method in a class in a method:

```
class A {
    void b() {
        class C {
            void d() {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that possibility. +1

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in java. However this can achieved by interface though the code becomes complex.

```
interface Block<T> {
  void invoke(T arg);
}
class Utils {
  public static <T> void forEach(Iterable<T> seq, Block<T> fct) {
    for (T elm : seq)
      fct.invoke(elm);
  }
}
public class MyExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);   
    Block<Integer> print = new Block<Integer>() {
      private String foo() {    // foo is declared inside main method and within the block
        return "foo";
      }
      public void invoke(Integer arg) {  
        print(foo() + "-" + arg);
      }
    };
    Utils.forEach(nums,print);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Java only allows a method to be defined within a class, not within another method.