# Can a method be called by an object inside of the same class?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to understand is why I'm receiving an error when I try to call a method by an object whilst residing in the same class.

My syntax looks correct. I understand the local variables inside of the method are uninitialized, and wanted to see if the compiler would be able to pick this up.

My issue however is, I receive a stupid error from the compiler, when I try to invoke the method on an object of the same class, within the class, as such.

```
class Wool {

public static void main (String [] args) {

int add() {
int x;
int a = x + 3;
return a;

}

Wool w = new Wool ();

System.out.print("something here " + w.add());


} // end main

} // end class
```

There error that I receive from the compiler is:

```
c Wool.java
Wool.java:5: ';' expected
int add() {
    ^
```

I can do the above fine, if the object of type Wool is instantiated in another class, and the object has no issue in invoking the method, to show me the compilation error that the local variables need a value in that method.

I just don't understand why I can't do it in one class. And if it is possible, please could you educate me.

Help would be immensely grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to define a method inside another method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, can a method/constructor declaration appear inside another method/constructor declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735922/in-java-can-a-method-constructor-declaration-appear-inside-another-method-const)

Comment: java dosn't support defining method declaration within a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define a method inside another one. You must declare the `add` method outside of the `main` method.

Change your code to

```
class Wool {

    int add() {
        int x = 0; // give a value to avoid another error
        int a = x + 3;
        return a;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {  
        Wool w = new Wool ();
        System.out.print("something here " + w.add());
    } // end main

} // end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a method inside `main()`. You can not do that.

Methods must be declared inside classes, not inside other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because `add()` is not defined as a class method, but you define it as "local" method within `main`, which is not allowed in `java`. You must change it to

```
class Woo{

void add(){

....
}

public static void main(String[] args){

new Woo().add();

...
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method *directly* inside a method:

```
main(){
add() {
}
}
```

that's illegal in java.

Answer (score 0):

Put your method add in the body of your class but not in the body of your method main. Or better : leave Java alone :)

Comment: Can it be called a mistake ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a method *inside* a method.

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] arts) {
     //
}

int add() {
    //
}
```